# Dependency relationship

Tags: uml

I have a question on dependency relationship in a class diagram. Is it correct to show that a class has an attribute of an interface type by specifying a dependency relationship? Or  this can be done with association only? I've read that a dependency relationship is used only for method's parameters or local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An association is just a particular form of dependency. So, to answer your question, yes it is correct (valid) to represent an association as a dependency, however using an association is more accurate.

In his book "UML Distilled", Martin Fowler defines dependencies like that:

> A dependency exists between two elements if changes to the definition of one element [...] may cause changes to the other [...]. With classes, dependencies exist for various reasons: one class sends a message to another; **one class has another as part of its data**; one class mentions another as a parameter to an operation.

Comment: "one class has another as part of its data" :). I also read this line, therefore I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_%28UML%29)

> A dependency in the Unified Modeling
>   Language exists between two defined
>   elements  if a change to the
>   definition of one may result in a
>   change to the other. In UML this is
>   indicated by a dashed line pointing
>   from the dependent (or client) to the
>   independent (or supplier) element.

So per the definition, it makes sense to show that a class has an attribute of an interface type by specifying a dependency relationship. I'm not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not forbidden in UML therefore it is allowed :-)